# Formik setFieldValue Inside a Function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik

If I have a functional component and want to set a value outside of the Formik tag, how would I do that? Below is the code that I have for further clarification.

```
function XYZScreen() {

    const someFunctionWithLogic = () => {
        // Set the value of the number field here...
    }
    
    return (
        <Screen>
            <Formik>
                <FormField name="number" placeholder="Number" />
             </Formik>
        </Screen>            
    );
}
```

I have reduced the code to as little as possible to simplify the question. The question might not make sense in the context of the question but I think it is clear what I am asking for.

If you need more code, please let me know, I am happy to provide it if needed.

Answer (score 26):

You can use the [`useFormik`](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik) hook instead:

```
import { useFormik } from 'Formik'

function XYZScreen() {

    const formikProps = useFormik({
        initialValues,
        validationSchema,
        onSubmit: yourSubmitFunction,
        ...etc
    })

    const someFunctionWithLogic = () => {
        // Set the value of the number field here:
        formikProps.setFieldValue("number", someNumber)
    }
    
    return (
        <Screen>
            {/* No need for Formik component */}
            <FormField 
                name="number" 
                placeholder="Number" 
                value={formikProps.values.number} // or whatever the value is
                onChange={formikProps.handleChange}
            />
        </Screen>            
    );
}
```

So you're basically setting up all your form props in the function body, and you have access to them there.  Formik has a lot of great helper hooks and functions, I highly recommend combing through the docs.

#### Edit: Another way

If you really like the `Formik` tag, you can keep using it.  Just create a `Formik` wrapper component, and use your custom logic in a descendant using `useFormikContext`:

```js
// FormWrapper.js

const FormWrapper = () => (
  <Formik
    initialValues={initialValues}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}
    onSubmit={yourOnSubmitFunction}
  >
    <SomeChild />
  </Formik>
)

// SomeChild.js

const SomeChild = () => {

  // returns all values and methods from your Formik tag
  const formikProps = useFormikContext()

  const someFunctionWithLogic = () => {
    formikProps.setFieldValue("number", someNumber)
  }
    
  return (
    <Screen>
      <FormField 
        name="number" 
        placeholder="Number" 
        value={formikProps.values.number} // or whatever the value is
        onChange={formikProps.handleChange}
      />
    </Screen>            
    );
}
```

Comment: Is there any advantage or disadvantage using the Forkim hook instead of the component? As of my understanding, the Formik component is the preferred way.

Comment: It really just depends on the context, and the rest of your code.  In your case, which is a single component form where you want to access formik methods outside of the render/return statement, this is the best way.  I think `useFormik` is pretty well established at this point.  I do love the `Formik` tag, because you can access all its state and helper functions from any descendant component with `useFormikContext`...I woudn't say there's a general rule about what's 'preferred' though.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! However, as you highlighted, is it still possible to use the Formik context in descendant components? I am asking this because I do have components that access the context. For example my custom FormField component.

Comment: Yes this is definitely possible.  I edited my answer.  Basically you need to create a wrapper that is *only* the `Formik` component, and all children of the formik component need to be a separate component, where you can use `useFormikContext` in the function body.  Aside from that, there is no simple way to access formik state and helpers from above the `Formik` tag in the component tree.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I have been doing in my descendant components and it works fine. The issue is that I need to access it in a function above the Formik component. 

The reason behind the question is, a barcode scanner component that calls a function after it has scanned succesfully. The function is above the Formik component as highlighted in the question. That's where I need to set the field value from. I guess what I could do is pass the setFieldValue function as a parameter to the function.

Comment: I found myself trying to do the same thing, and I had to rethink what is considered "part of the form".  I was coming up with all kinds of crazy stuff to pass the `setFieldValue` and `resetForm` functions to a parent with a callback using a `useEffect`...it got very messy.  I decided that any element that interacts with the form is ultimately part of the form.  If you can manage lift your Formik component up so that it contains your barcode component, that would be ideal.  I'm not sure how you could pass it as a param to a function that is outside its scope, but if you're creative, good luck

Answer (score 3):

I just faced similar issue myself, and came up with another solution extending comment from Seth Lutske. You could combine using `useFormik` together with manual creation of Formik context. `useFormik` is very powerful, but it's downside is that it does not create a context, thus you cannot use `useField` or `useFormikContext` in child components, and need to manually pass them all the related props (value, onChange, onBlur etc).

What you can do is to create a Formik context object using `useFormik`, and pass context down manually using `<FormikProvider>`. With this approach, you can continue using all the fields as if they were wrapped in `<Formik>`

```js
import { useFormik, FormikProvider } from 'formik'

function XYZScreen() {
    const formikProps = useFormik({
        initialValues,
        validationSchema,
        onSubmit: yourSubmitFunction,
        ...etc
    })

    const someFunctionWithLogic = () => {
        // Set the value of the number field here:
        formikProps.setFieldValue("number", someNumber)
    }
    
    return (
        <Screen>
          {/* FormikProvider component instead of Formik */}
          <FormikProvider value={formikProps}>  
            <FormField 
              name="number" 
              placeholder="Number" 
            />
          </FormikProvider>  
        </Screen>            
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve this is by passing setFieldValue function to the function which you want so the code should look like this

```
function XYZScreen() {

const someFunctionWithLogic = (value, setFieldValue) => {
    // Set the value of the number field here...
    setFieldValue('price', value)
}

return (
    <Screen>
        <Formik>
            <FormField name="number" placeholder="Number" onChange={(e) => { handleChange(e); someFunctionWithLogic(value, setFieldValue ); }} />
         </Formik>
    </Screen>            
);
}
```

Reference https://web-brackets.com/discussion/12/how-to-use-setfieldvalue-from-outside-render-function-formik

Comment: This is still triggering the function call from within the Formik form. The ideal solution is to be able to call it completely outside of the Formik form.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this easily with `initialValues`

```
 <Formik
    initialValues={{
      "fieldName": this.state.value,
    }}
    enableReinitialize
    ...
 >
 ...
</Formik>
```

Also for functional components, you can do this with `useEffect` inside `Formik`, set the value using `const [value,setValue] = useState()`

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{}}
  onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => _submit(values, resetForm)}
  validationSchema={buildValidationSchema(actionItem.fields)}
>
{({ setFieldValue, handleSubmit, values, errors, touched }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
       setFieldValue("fieldName",value); 
    }, [value]); 
...
</Formik>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try resetting the form using `initialProps`?

```js
function XYZScreen() {

    const [number, setNumber] = useState()

    const someFunctionWithLogic = () => {
        // Set the value of the number field here...
        setNumber(...)
    }
    
    return (
        <Screen>
            <Formik initialProps={{number}}>
                <FormField name="number" placeholder="Number" />
             </Formik>
        </Screen>            
    );
}
```

Another suggestion is to pass that number to the inner component of Formik:

```js
function SomeChild(props) {
    const {number, setFieldValue} = props;
    
    useEffect(() => {
       setFieldValue('number', number);
    }, [number]);

    return (
       <FormField name="number" placeholder="Number" />
    )
}

function XYZScreen() {

    const [number, setNumber] = useState()

    const someFunctionWithLogic = () => {
        // Set the value of the number field here...
        setNumber(...)
    }
    
    return (
        <Screen>
            <Formik>
                {(props) => <SomeChild number={number} {...props} />
             </Formik>
        </Screen>            
    );
}
```

Comment: What if there is multiple initialProps? Wouldn't that overwrite any other values?

Comment: initialProps will be the resetting the form. So, you need to save the all of the form values in the parent component, specifically XYZScreen, as soon as the form value is updated from Formik.

Comment: Formik advices not to use the state with Formik. If I would do it this way, I do not see the benefit of using Formik anymore since I would largely interact with the state.

Comment: I see. Let me know if you can try second suggestion.

Comment: I prefer that solution but it also has some flaws. Firstly, I would need to abstract every single field; in a form with 20 fields, that is too much work. Secondly, setting initial values would also be more tedious and would need to be done through the state.

Comment: This is the issue I was primarily facing. Everything seems like a workaround and nothing seems to be straightforward.

Comment: Exactly. Setting formik data from outside is a workaround. Ideally, it'll be great if you can add someFunctionWithLogic handler inside the formik component.

Comment: By the way, I think using initialProps is not a preferable way.
Here is the codesandbox link with second approach.
https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-test-forked-8yh2g
Thank you for sharing ideas.